# Time Complexity of a loop iteration by i^2

Tags: time-complexity

```
i=2;
while(i<n) {
   i = i*i;
   //O(1) complexity here
}
```

I'm new to time complexity and trying to figure out what this would be.
I know that if the iteration would've been i=2*i then it'd be O(log(n)) but I don't really know how I can calculate iterations of i^2.

Intuitively it'd also be O(log(n)) because it "iterates faster" but I don't know how to formally explain this.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can neatly translate this into the `i = 2 * i` case you mentioned by considering the mathematical log of `i`. Pseudocode for how this value changes:

```
log_i = log(2);
while (log_i < log_n) {
    log_i = 2 * log_i;
    // O(1) stuff here
}
```

It should be clear from this that the time complexity is O(log log n), assuming constant multiplication cost of course.

Comment: Thanks! could you please explain why does i = i*i become log_i = 2 * log_i?

Comment: @Shakshouk log rules: log(a^b) = b log a, so log (i^2) = 2 log i.

Comment: yeah but wouldn't i*i become log_i * log_i? meaning (log_i)^2 and then the log rule doesn't apply?

Comment: No, I'm keeping track of the value of log(i), which doubles when i is squared. Addition with logs is the same as ordinary multiplication, so i*i "becomes" log_i + log_i.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to approach this problem just using mathematics.

Consider your variable `i`. What sequence does it take? It seems to be

*2, 4, 16, 16<sup>2</sup>, ...*

If you look at it for a bit, you notice that this sequence is just

*2, 2<sup>2</sup>, (2<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup>, ((2<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup>, ...* or

*2<sup>1</sup>, 2<sup>2</sup>, 2<sup>4</sup>, 2<sup>8</sup>, ...* which is

*2<sup>2<sup>0</sup></sup>, 2<sup>2<sup>1</sup></sup>, 2<sup>2<sup>2</sup></sup>, 2<sup>2<sup>3</sup></sup>, ...*

so general term for this sequence is ***2<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup>*** where *k = 0, 1, 2, ...*

Now, how many iterations does your loop make? It will be in the order of *k* when *2<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup> = n*. So let us solve this equation:

*2<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup> = n* <sub>(apply *log<sub>2</sub>* to both sides)</sub>

*2<sup>k</sup> = log<sub>2</sub>n* <sub>(apply *log<sub>2</sub>* to both sides again)</sub>

*k = log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>2</sub>n)*

In big-O notation, the base of the logarithm doesn't matter, so we say your algorithm has a time complexity of:

***O(log log n)***.